# How do I add a "Cancel" button on the subscriptions listing page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

I have managed to find the action where I can add the code for the button, but the problem is that I can't find how to create a cancel link anywhere. Does anyone know how to do it?

So here is the code I got so far:

```
function woocommerce_cancel_button() { ?>

<a href="#" class="button view"><?php echo esc_html_x( 'Cancel', 'cancel a subscription', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></a>

    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_subscriptions_actions', 'woocommerce_cancel_button', 10 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing but couldn't find it anywhere so I tried to do it myself. Here's my code by the way. Hope this helps.

```
function addCancelButton($subscription) {
    $actions = wcs_get_all_user_actions_for_subscription( $subscription, get_current_user_id() );
    if(!empty($actions)){
        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ){
            if(strtolower($action['name']) == "cancel"){
                $cancelLink = esc_url( $action['url'] );
                echo "<a href='$cancelLink' class='button cancel'>".$action['name']."</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_subscriptions_actions', 'addCancelButton', 10 );
```